# Using htaccess to block port?

Tags: apache-2.2

Using htaccess to block port in apache?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

### No.

In order to have Apache process the `.htaccess` file's directives the port needed to be open, and a client needed to connect to it.

What you might be looking for is using iptables to block the port.

Answer (score 2):

You theoretically CAN use rewrite rules in .htaccess using the `%{SERVER_PORT}` variable to do something different with requests coming in on a specific port, which could also mean denying access to resources.

However, this is almost certainly *not* the best way to get to what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

please use RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !3306$